# Convert from class to Interface with a generic type interface Interface<Interface>

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am having trouble down-converting a class to it's base interface.  I have the following (simplified):

```
public interface ITaxonomy
{
    string CommonName { get; set; }
    string ScientificName { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaxonomyHasChildren<TChild> : ITaxonomy where TChild : ITaxonomy
{
    ICollection<TChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaxonomyHasParent<TParent> : ITaxonomy where TParent : ITaxonomy
{
    TParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to extract the data back out in my VM:

```
private void SelectedEntityChanged(ITaxonomy selectedEntity)
{
    CommonName = selectedEntity.CommonName;
    ScientificName = selectedEntity.ScientificName;

    Children = selectedEntity.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(ITaxonomyHasChildren<ITaxonomy>.Children))?
        .GetValue(selectedEntity) as ICollection<ITaxonomy>;

    Parent = selectedEntity.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(ITaxonomyHasParent<ITaxonomy>.Parent))?
        .GetValue(selectedEntity) as ITaxonomy;
}
```

The `Children` part doesn't work, I am assuming because it doesn't like converting from `ICollection<MyClass>` to `ICollection<ITaxonomy>`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Expand "Doesn't work", is there an exception? What is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to make your generic interfaces [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654058.aspx). But since `ICollection<T>` is not covariant, it would require also changing the `Children` type to `IReadOnlyCollection<TChild>` and remove the setters if you can afford that.

```
public interface ITaxonomyHasChildren<out TChild> : ITaxonomy where TChild : ITaxonomy
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<TChild> Children { get; }
}

public interface ITaxonomyHasParent<out TParent> : ITaxonomy where TParent : ITaxonomy
{
    TParent Parent { get; }
}
```

This will also allow you to avoid reflection:

```
private void SelectedEntityChanged(ITaxonomy selectedEntity)
{
    CommonName = selectedEntity.CommonName;
    ScientificName = selectedEntity.ScientificName;

    Children = (selectedEntity as ITaxonomyHasChildren<ITaxonomy>)?.Children;
    Parent = (selectedEntity as ITaxonomyHasParent<ITaxonomy>)?.Parent;
}
```

A sample class implementation:

```
class Taxonomy : ITaxonomy, ITaxonomyHasChildren<Taxonomy>, ITaxonomyHasParent<Taxonomy>
{
    public string CommonName { get; set; }
    public string ScientificName { get; set; }
    public Taxonomy Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Taxonomy> Children { get; set; } = new List<Taxonomy>();
    IReadOnlyCollection<Taxonomy> ITaxonomyHasChildren<Taxonomy>.Children => Children;
}
```

Comment: `ICollection<T>` is not covariant, and you can't keep the setters.

Comment: @Lee Just realized the same.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind - I don't really like the idea of making items read-only as all of these items will be editable at run-time, but i can see ways around that if I need to, just adds in a lot of extra work that I would like to avoid.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols Yeah, I agree it's far from ideal, but that's so far the only way to get at least some small polymorphic behavior. `IEnumerable<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` are the only standard interfaces that allow such casting.

Comment: Actually, this worked really well as was easier than I thought.  The only thing I am not liking is that I had to change my `ICollection` to a `List`.

Comment: It looks like I can use `ICollection` and then do `Children => Children as IReadOnyCollection<T>`  -- is there any draw back to that instead of a `List`?

Comment: You mean in the implementing class? As soon as the actual collection class (the one that implements `ICollection<T>`) also implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, there will not be a problem. `List<T>` does that, so do `HashSet<T>` and `Collection<T>` (and derived from it like `ObservableCollection<T>`).

Answer (score 2):

Invoking

```
selectedEntity.GetType()
     .GetProperty( nameof(ITaxonomyHasChildren<ITaxonomy>.Children) )
     .GetValue( selectedEntity )
```

is an extremely roundabout way of doing things.

You should not need to use the reflection system to accomplish basic object oriented stuff.

Also, your types are extremely complicated for no good reason.

Consider this instead:

```
public interface IParent<T> //note: general-purpose interface unrelated to taxonomies
{
    ICollection<T> Children { get; }
}

public interface IChild<T> //note: general-purpose interface unrelated to taxonomies
{
    T Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaxonomy
{
    string CommonName { get; set; }
    string ScientificName { get; set; }
    IParent<ITaxonomy> AsParent {get; } //returns `null` if not a parent
    IChild<ITaxonomy> AsChild {get; } //returns `null` if not a child
}

IChild<ITaxonomy> selectedEntityAsChild = selectedEntity.AsChild;
if( selectedEntityAsChild != null )
{
    ITaxonomy parent = selectedEntityAsChild.Parent;
    ...
}

IParent<ITaxonomy> selectedEntityAsParent = selectedEntity.AsParent;
if( selectedEntityAsParent != null )
{
    ICollection<ITaxonomy> children = selectedEntityAsParent.Children;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not all taxonomies have parents and/or children hence the separation.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols yes, of course, and that's why the `AsParent` getter will return `null` if the taxonomy on which you invoke it is not a parent, as the example code shows.

Comment: You also have the option of declaring `class MyParentTaxonomy: ITaxonomy, IParent<ITaxonomy>` and then doing `selectedEntityAsParent = selectedEntity as IParent<ITaxonomy>`, but that's more cryptic.

Comment: I see where your going with this now - was reading off my phone and missed the full context.  It's a good idea and I'll give it a shot - but I don't think this will resolve the actual issue.

Comment: Tried to get this working - but the main issue still exists of not being able to convert over - I'm sure it's doable this way, but Ivan's answer works better for me.